# Magento 2 Price Different version 2.0.7

Tags: magento2, price, tierprice

Got a strange issue in Magento 2 on a Configurable Product:

All size 4,5 and 6’s should be £289.00 and have no VAT attached
All size 7’s should be 249.167 and have VAT attached

So I’ve se the config as the 4/5/6 price with not VAT and gone into the size 7’s simples and changed the price and clicked None VAT.

However on the front end the price is going funny, it is showing it as a special price ‘was £289.00 now £249.17’ when it should just be showing £289.00 then on the dropdown when you pick a 7 size it should change to £299.00.

I have checked in the back-end and there is no product using special price. Could this be a Magento 2 bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's looks like a bug. Please create issue on the [github](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues)